# What could be the Consequence of inserting "id" in any autoincrementing 'id' containing table?

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

What could be the Consequence of inserting "id" in any autoincrementing 'id' containing table?

If I have a Tabe in which I have configured the column "id" as the auto incrmented, But still I am using an INSERT query in which id is defined, like wise `INSERT INTO XYZ (id) values ('26');` 
How does it going to effect the table and the process related to it..
Is it "no issues" to do this? or it should be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you need to.  The table keeps track of what the `AUTO_INCREMENT` number is at, and if you insert a number equal to or higher than this number, then MySQL adjusts the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value appropriately.

Basically, inserts always start from the highest auto_increment id + 1, and you can insert specific ids with no problems.

Comment: Dont U Think that Problem Could be in the case when two tables of similar structures needs to be synchronized?